# One To Many relationship properties not functioning as expected. Cannot Retrieve List of Members from Group records - NestJS TypeORM

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

Is there anyone willing to help me understand TypeORM and Nestjs? I keep getting this unbearably annoying error "`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`" and I'm sure it has something to do with relations but cant figure out how to get it to work.

I have a Group entity that has a OneToMany relationship with my User entity (i.e. each user can only belong to one group at a time, but group can have many users.)
What I have been trying to do is create two route handlers. One, that uses a group id and user id to  adds a user to a group's member list and another route handler, that given a group id, returns the list of members from that group.

My `getMembersList` method throws a `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')` when I attempt to return my `group.members` array. From what I understand, typeorm doesnt expose certain properties on an entity unless explicitly stated (e.g.`relations: {members: true}`) and that could be the reason the id property is undefined for what im guessing is regarding the user, probably because I didnt expose my User's `group` property, but honestly I dont know why that would be the case when Im not querying my database for any specific users.

Likewise, in my `addMember` method I can apparently add a user to the Groups members list if I go through the User entity (e.g. `user.group = group;`) but I cant seem to add a user to the members list through the Group entity (i.e. `group.members.push(user)`). When I try to add the user via `group.members.push(user)` typeOrm does not associate the Users `groupId` column with the corresponding group (i.e. when I inspect my User table the `groupId` column is null)
I honestly just don't get it..

Below are some of the relevant code snippets. (I removed the imports for brevity)

**group.entity.ts**

```
@Entity()
export class Group {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToOne(() => User, { cascade: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  owner: User;

  @OneToMany(() => User, (user) => user.group, { cascade: true })
  members: User[];
}
```

**user.entity.ts**

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Group, (group) => group.members)
  group: Group;
}
```

**groups.controller.ts**

```
  @Patch('/add-member/:id')
  @Serialize(GroupListDto)
  async addMember(@Param('id') groupId, @Body() body) {
    return this.groupsService.addMember(+groupId, body);
  }


  @Get('/get-members/:id')
  @Serialize(GroupListDto)
  async getMembersList(@Param('id') groupId: string) {
    return this.groupsService.getMembersList(+groupId);
  }
```

**group-list.dto.ts**

```
export class GroupListDto {
  @Expose()
  id: number;

  @Expose()
  name: string;

  @Expose()
  @Type(() => UserDto) 
  user: UserDto;

}

export class UserDto {
  @Expose()
  id: number;

  @Expose()
  email: string;

}
```

**groups.service.ts**

```
async getMembersList(groupId: number) {
   const group = await this.groupsRepository.findOne({
      where: { id: groupId},
      relations: { members: true },
    });

    if (!group) {
      throw new NotFoundException('Group not found');
    }
    console.log('GET MEMBERS');
    console.log(group.members);

    return group.members;
  }

async addMember(groupId: number, body: GroupListDto) {
    const res = await this.entityManager.transaction(async (entityManager) => {
      const group = await this.groupRepository.findOne({
        where: { id: groupId},
        relations: { members: true },
      });

      if (!group) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Group not found');
      }

      // Assigning the group via the members array doesnt seem to work
      group.members.push(user);
      await this.entityManager.save(group);
      console.log(group.members);

      // Assigning the group via the user seems to work?
      // const user = await this.usersRepository.findOne({
      //   where: { id: body.user.id },
      //   relations: { group: true },
      // });

      // user.group = group;
      // await this.entityManager.save(user);
    });

    return res;
  }
```

**sample requests**

```
### add member 1 to group 2 (addUser)
PATCH http://localhost:3000/groups/add-member/2
Content-Type: application/json

{
    
    "user": {"id": 1}
}


### Get all Users in group 2 (getMemberList)
GET http://localhost:3000/groups/get-members/2
```

Any advice is very much appreciated

I tried adding @JoinTable() to my group property on the User entity. I tried adding it to the members property on the Group entity. I tried adding it separately and to both at the same time.
I tried adding { cascade: true } to my group property on the User entity. I tried adding it to the members property on the Group entity. I tried adding it separately and to both at the same time.

I tried changing the DTOs.

I tried with `EntityManager` and with `groupsRepository`

I tried running within `entityManager.transaction()`and without it.

I tried adding a user to the member list by assigning the group to users.group.

When I `console.log()` the objects. the id properties the error complains about apparently exist. The `members` list is populated with the user I `pushed` into the array. likewise, the `Group` values are displayed and I see an `id` value. Same goes for the `User`. The error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')` occurs when I run `this.entityManager.save()`

Edit:

The error is being triggered by a Dto applied to the entire Group controller that looks like the following:

**group.dto.ts**

```
import { Expose, Transform } from 'class-transformer';

export class GroupDto {
  @Expose()
  id: number;

  @Expose()
  @Transform(({ obj }) => obj.owner.id)
  ownerId: number;

  @Expose()
  id: number;

  @Expose()
  name: string;

  @Expose()
  @Type(() => UserDto) 
  user: UserDto;
}
```

Originally, I had an `owner` property that got set when a Group was created. I stripped it away to narrow down the causes for the error and when I removed the `ownerId` property from the `GroupDto` the error was resolved, so exposing this `ownerId` property appears to be the root cause.

The `ownerId` exists so I dont expose the full user object in my responses. I have added that property back to the Group entity above. When I have this property in the Dto I am not able to get my list of members. How am I supposed to expose my ownerId so it doesnt break my functions?

Comment: ownerId exists but your DTO doesn't have an owner object, so you can't "dot operator" id in undefined value